# How to convert a date string like “2011-06-25T11:00:26+01:00” to a long like iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I need to convert this string date "2011-06-25T11:00:26+01:00” into a long like value.

I tried this

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];

[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ssZ"];

NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:[time stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"T" withString:@""]];

[df setDateFormat:@"eee MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm"];

NSLog(@"time%@", time);
long lgTime =  (long)[date timeIntervalSince1970];
```

but this doesn't work. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809379/convert-nsstring-to-nsdate

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, I missed this the first time but `"2011-06-25T11:00:26+01:00”` is cannot be parsed. The correct string would be `"2011-06-25T11:00:26+0100”`.

Once you've the string in that format, use the date format – `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"`.

#### Example usage

```
NSString * time = @"2011-06-25T11:00:26+0100";

NSDateFormatter *df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];  
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];

NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:time];

long lgTime = (long)[date timeIntervalSince1970];

NSLog(@"%ld", lgTime);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I tried this but it doesn't give me long like value.
NSDateFormatter *df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"]];
    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ssZ"];
    NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:time];

    [df setDateFormat:@"eee MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm"];
    
    NSLog(@"time%@", time);
    long lgTime =  (long)[date timeIntervalSince1970];

Comment: Blunder. I meant `setDateFormat:` but typed in `setTimeZone:` or rather copied it wrong I guess. As such I've corrected my answer, take a look.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert "**2011-06-25T11:00:26+01:00**” to "**2011-06-25T11:00:26GMT+01:00**" which can be parsed

```
NSMutableString *string=[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"2011-06-25T11:00:26+01:00"];

NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:@"+" options:NSBackwardsSearch];
[string insertString:@"GMT" atIndex:range.location];
NSLog(@"string is %@",string);
```

Hope this helps you