# NSDateFormatter question

Tags: iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I want to parse this date: "2009-08-24T05:20:00"

I have tried this, but doesn't work:

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"];
```

any ideas ?

Comment: You should see [`this`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502284/how-to-convert-a-date-string-like-2011-06-25t1100260100-to-a-long-like-ipho/6502301#6502301)

Comment: Make sure the phone's not in a 24 hour locale but set to 12 hour display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a category for this:

NSString+DateParse.h

```
@interface NSString (DateParse) 

-(NSDate *) dateFromISO8601;

@end
```

NSString+DateParse.m

```
@implementation NSString (DateParse) 

-(NSDate *) dateFromISO8601 {

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSString *format = ([self hasSuffix:@"Z"]) ? @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'" : @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz";
    [formatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
    [formatter setDateFormat:format];
    [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
    return [formatter dateFromString:self];

}

@end
```

So, suppose if you have a string called `strDate`:

```
NSDate * dtParsed = [strDate dateFromISO8601];
```

Comment: Yes, this works (although a bit too much for my small problem). thanks. however i now have to pick the correct answer and there appear to be more than one correct answer :)

Answer (score 2):

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
```

You have to use apostrophe around the T.

Comment: Yes, this works. thanks. however i now have to pick the correct answer and there appear to be more than one correct answer :)

Answer (score 2):

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"];
```

Try this

Comment: Yes, this works. thanks. however i now have to pick the correct answer and there appear to be more than one correct answer :)