# How to convert nsstring into nsdate in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i want to convert an nsstring into nsdate .i have created a global variable  where i saving the date picked from the datepicker and then converting this variable to nsdate us the datefromstring function.But the  string is not getting converted to date.What may be the problem.

```
TTimePickercontroller:
This is the class in which i have the code for the picker

-(NSString *)convertDueDateFormat{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    [dateFormatter setFormatterBehavior: NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date];

    return dateString;
//dateString is an nsstring variable that has been declared globally.
}

TAddAlarmController.
this is another class in which i want to convert the dateString varibale into nssdate
-(IBAction)save{

    timepicker = [[TTimePickerController alloc]init];
    NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"hh:mm"];
    d = [df dateFromString:dateString];
    NSLog(@"%@", d);
    //Here i am using the dateFromString function and converting the string variable dateString into nsdate variable d .in dateString variable value is getting passed but in d the value is not getting passed. 


}
Please help me in solving the problem.Thanks
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert NSString to NSDate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809379/convert-nsstring-to-nsdate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this code this will help you because I run this code successfully and return time.

UIDatePicker *pickerView = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 0, 0)];  
pickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;  
pickerView.hidden = NO;  
pickerView.date = [NSDate date];
[self.view addSubview:pickerView];
NSString *dateString;   
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm"];
dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:pickerView.date];
NSLog(@"String into Date:--->%@",dateString);
```

Comment: nikunj but but when i convert this dateStrimg to nsdate it is not getting properly converted.

Comment: if i select 1.00 pm it displays 7.30 pm in my nsdate variable

Comment: just wait 10 min i implement your demo

Comment: try this link this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917250/converting-nsstring-to-nsdate-and-back-again

Comment: why you required nsdate & wherever you display? plz tell me so i solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

```
-(NSString *)convertDueDateFormat{

 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm"];
 dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date];
   ////some code
```

}

```
Try like this,
```

Comment: but when i am converting it to d in console it displays :1970-01-01 05:24:00 +0000